# How can I just get the "Year" portion from the output of timespan( ) in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, timespan

I have a "Date of Birth" field, and trying to use the `timespan()` method to get the age in years. But returns "28 Years, 2 Months, 2 Weeks, 3 Days, 15 Hours, 16 Minutes".

Any idea how I can just get the "28 Years" portion?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use PHP's strftime() function. Instead of using the CI's timespan().

`echo strftime('%Y', 1226239392);`

Answer (score 0):

### There are many ways to do this, with the string in $date, like so:

```
$date = '28 Years, 2 Months, 2 Weeks, 3 Days, 15 Hours, 16 Minutes';
```

This will give you "28 Years"

```
$yearsPart = substr($date, 0, strpos($date, 'Years') + 5);
```

So will this:

```
$parts = split(', ', $date);
$yearsPart = $parts[0];
```